# I want to get customer name that ends with g but %g is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * 
from customer 
where UPPER(cname) LIKE 'J%G';
```

Comment: More info needed. What records in your table should be matched by this, for example? Maybe you don't *have* a customer that starts with `j` and ends with `g`.

Comment: align your codes please

Comment: Do your desired `cname` values need to start with `J`?  Also, it can help if you provide a copy of the error message that you are given.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to end in G then use this

```
 select * 
 from customer 
 where UPPER(cname) LIKE '%G';
```

If it does not seem to finish try this:

```
 select * 
 from (
   select top 1000 *
   from customer with #nolock
 ) X
 where UPPER(cname) LIKE '%G';
```

Comment: It deos not work. I did try 'G%' works and find every name which start with g but ends with not working

Comment: @manvirajrah  Define does not work.  If it is slow that is to be expected -- it will be much slower because it needs to check all strings of all sizes.  I made an exit... try that and see if works.